# SFDX: Create Project failed to run

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin

Facing problem to complete this trailhead trail ( https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code)

I have installed Salesforce CLi and VSCode and JDK 11.

I've attempted multiple times to create a project using shortcut ctrl+shift+p and mention the name of project and it produces the below error:

SFDX: Create Project failed to run
Source: Salesforce CLI Integration (Extension)

Output of Git tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log command:

{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-LTRGFTM","pid":25000,"log":"ApexLogTailCommand","level":50,"msg":"[ '\u001b[1mERROR running force:apex:log:tail: \u001b[22m',\n  '\u001b[31mUnexpected argument: ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log\u001b[39m\n\u001b[31mSee more help with --help\u001b[39m' ]","time":"2020-01-29T20:33:46.364Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-LTRGFTM","pid":2820,"log":"ApexLogTailCommand","level":50,"msg":"[ '\u001b[1mERROR running force:apex:log:tail: \u001b[22m',\n  '\u001b[31mMust pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.\u001b[39m' ]","time":"2020-01-29T20:34:31.092Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-LTRGFTM","pid":51532,"log":"ApexLogTailCommand","level":50,"msg":"[ '\u001b[1mERROR running force:apex:log:tail: \u001b[22m',\n  '\u001b[31mFlag --loglevel expects a value\u001b[39m' ]","time":"2020-01-29T20:36:28.159Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-LTRGFTM","pid":22680,"log":"ApexLogTailCommand","level":50,"msg":"[ '\u001b[1mERROR running force:apex:log:tail: \u001b[22m',\n  '\u001b[31mMust pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.\u001b[39m' ]","time":"2020-01-29T20:37:22.332Z","v":0}

VS Code Output from Create Project
Starting SFDX: Create Project

13:53:46.450 sfdx force:project:create --projectname HelloWorldLightningWebComponent --outputdir c:\Users\RogerMiller\OneDrive - Cloud for Good\VS Code --template standard
'sfdx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
13:53:46.480 sfdx force:project:create --projectname HelloWorldLightningWebComponent --outputdir c:\Users\RogerMiller\OneDrive - Cloud for Good\VS Code --template standard ended with error spawn sfdx ENOENT
Salesforce CLI is not installed. Install it from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli

However, SFDX CLI is installed: sfdc -v yields: sfdx-cli/7.36.0-b1c4e9c7c8 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: CLI is updated.

Comment: What do you get in return when you type ``sfdx -v`` in your OS' terminal?

Comment: Could you `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` and post the output here.?

Comment: Command Line response:Salesforce CLI

VERSION
  sfdx-cli/7.36.0-b1c4e9c7c8 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

USAGE
  $ sfdx [COMMAND]

COMMANDS
  commands  list all the commands
  force     tools for the Salesforce developer
  help      display help for sfdx
  plugins   add/remove/create CLI plug-ins
  update    update the sfdx CLI
  which     show which plugin a command is in

TOPICS
  Run help for each topic below to view subcommands

  commands  list all the commands
  force     tools for the Salesforce developer
  plugins   add/remove/create CLI plug-ins

Comment: Per another post on trailblazer community (https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000peZwQAI), I also tried uninstalling the CLI and VS Code and am receiving the same error message as original post.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm unsure of your request. I've tried sfdx force:apex:log:tail --loglevel DEBUG and get "Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance." error message. You likely had something else in mind.

Comment: @mountainrog Sorry, `tail` is just a normal bash command. Type it in verbatim in your shell (Git Bash, mingw32, xterm, whatever), it should give you the last bits of the file in question. It might be useless, but you might also see something useful in there.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Posted the results of the log tail in the original post.

Comment: @mountainrog Umm, you'll want to rerun the command then get the log from there. These errors are just related to the tail command you tried to run.

Comment: @sfdcfox - That was the only output even when the create project was rerun. See the output from VS Code now in OP. VS Code is not seeming to recognize that CLI is installed even though it is.

Comment: For some reason, VS Code is not finding the sfdx executable in your path (the list of folders searched for an executable program when you run a command). Is there any chance VS Code was running while you installed sfdx? Try a good ol' reboot - that may help VS Code start with knowledge of your current path.

Comment: @sfdxfox I wouldn't expect there to be anything useful in sfdx.log - VS Code isn't able to find the executable to run it, so it's not going to have written anything in its log.

Comment: I would also check, if you're on windows, that the path variable is set correctly. Here's  [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/troubleshooting/) on troubleshooting